# Blender 3.4 Error: Unable to open or write bookmark file

Tags: add-on, windows, installation

So I am getting the following error in Blender 3.4:

> Unable to open or write bookmark file "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\config\bookmarks.txt"

I get this error when I try adding an add-on. Don't know why. I fully uninstalled 3.3 (like the dummy I am I also forgot to keep my config file) and installed 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permissions related issue- I have found running Blender as administrator solved the problem.